# How to include html (`flextable`) inside an md/github document using `webshot` and `phantomjs`?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, webshot

I never had problems using the `webshot` package and `phantomjs` to automatically take a screenshot of an html table and include the screenshot in the rendered document, such as on an GitHub README document. For reference, see: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-widgets.html

> HTML widgets (https://www.htmlwidgets.org) are typically interactive JavaScript applications, which only work in HTML output. If you knit an Rmd document containing HTML widgets to a non-HTML format such as PDF or Word, you may get an error message like this:
>
> `Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting X output. Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of your rmarkdown file:`
>
> `always_allow_html: yes`
>
> `Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.`
>
> There is actually a better solution than the one mentioned in the above error message, but it involves extra packages. You can install the webshot package (Chang 2022) in R and also install PhantomJS:
>
> `install.packages("webshot")`
>
> `webshot::install_phantomjs()`
>
> Then if you knit an Rmd document with HTML widgets to a non-HTML format, the HTML widgets will be displayed as static screenshots. The screenshots are automatically taken in knitr.

However, a couple months ago, it stopped working for objects from the `flextable` package, whereas, it still works for other html objects like `DT` tables. The `flextable` author is not sure of the cause of this change in behaviour, and it might have nothing to do with `flextable` package. I was wondering if anybody else can reproduce, and perhaps, point out a solution. Thanks.

Here is my attempt at a reprex:

````
---
output:
  github_document
---

```{r versions}
packageVersion("webshot")
## [1] '0.5.4'

packageVersion("webshot2")
## [1] '0.1.0'

packageVersion("flextable")
## [1] '0.9.2.2'

webshot::is_phantomjs_installed()
## [1] TRUE

webshot::install_phantomjs()
## It seems that the version of `phantomjs` installed is greater than or equal to the 
requested version.To install the requested version or downgrade to another version, use 
`force = TRUE`.

webshot::install_phantomjs(force = TRUE)
## Warning in utils::download.file(url, method = method, ...): the 'wininet'
## method is deprecated for http:// and https:// URLs

## phantomjs has been installed to C:\Users\rempsyc\AppData\Roaming\PhantomJS
```

```{r DT}
DT::datatable(head(iris))
```
````

[image]

````
```{r flextable, eval = TRUE}
flextable::flextable(head(iris))

Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting 
gfm+tex_math_dollars-yaml_metadata_block output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML.
If your aiming to have some HTML widgets shown in non-HTML format as a screenshot,
please install webshot or webshot2 R package for knitr to do the screenshot.
Alternatively, you can allow HTML output in non-HTML formats
by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: true

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution is to regress to `knitr` version 1.40.**

---

`knitr` version 1.41 and above now breaks the natural html `flextable` to `webshot` image integration for GitHub/md documents. I have opened a GitHub issue about this bug: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2265

Answer (score 1):

**DT** is a htmlwidget while **flextable** is not. So the automatic screenshoting that **knitr** can do won't apply for such objects. **knitr** will do a screenshot only when **webshot** or **webshot2** is available, and for htmlwidgets objects, shiny apps, or embeded URLs.

I don't think **flexable** is outputing markdown at all. So, I would say you need to use a function that will transform the output.

For non supported output as native, **flextable** now supports into a grid objects, so it can behave like a plot in a R Markdown context. This is shown at https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/plotting-flextable.html

````r
---
title: "flextable as plot"
output: 
  github_document: default
---

```{r}
plot(flextable::flextable(head(iris)))
```
````

This is for now manual, but maybe `knit_print.flextable` could do that by default for markdown output as the complex HTML output is not supported.

Hope it helps.